# LibGdx - How can I not load my textures every single frame?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am kinda new to Java and LibGdx but for my school project I need to Animate a Player-Sprite.
For only one Animation per Player everything went fine with the Methode I made for this but now I also need a Walking, Idling and Fighting Animation. I managed to get the Animations to switch but the Problem is now, that only one Frame of each Animation gets Displayed. After some research I know that I need to stop updating my Textures every frame but I cant get to know how to do so.
So far Ive tried a simple timer before updating but this just looks weird.
Here is my Code:

```
public Player(){
        img3 = new Texture("platform_metroidvania asset pack v1.01/herochar sprites(new)/herochar_idle_anim_strip_4.png");
        img = new Texture("platform_metroidvania asset pack v1.01/herochar sprites(new)/herochar_idle_anim_strip_4.png");
        img1 = new Texture("platform_metroidvania asset pack v1.01/herochar sprites(new)/herochar_run_anim_strip_6.png");
        img2 = new Texture("platform_metroidvania asset pack v1.01/herochar sprites(new)/herochar_sword_attack_anim_strip_4.png");

        animation();
        changeCharacter();
    }



    public static void animation(){
        if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
            img3 = img2;
            amount = 3;
            tileWidth = 32;
        }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
            img3 = img1;
            tileWidth = 16;
            amount = 3;
        }else{
            img3 = img;
            amount = 3;
            tileWidth = 16;
        }
    }

    public static void changeCharacter(){
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        regions = TextureRegion.split(img3, tileWidth, 16);
        sprite = new Sprite(regions[0][0]);
        sprite.setPosition(x,y);

        Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame++;
                if (frame > amount) {
                    frame = 0;
                }
                sprite.setRegion(regions[0][frame]);
            }
        }, 0, 1 / 12f);

    }
```

Both Methodes "animation" and "changeCharacter" are called in render().
I know there are simpler solutions for this in LibGdx but the rest of my code is based on this and I basically would have to rewrite the entire Project...
If you need any other classes just ask. I'm probably asking a very easy thing but I dont know what to do with this.

Comment: Do not create your SpriteBatch in a method that's called in `render()`. That will create a huge memory leak and eventually crash your game. Create the SpriteBatch one time in `create()`. As for your question, are you allowed to use the libGDX animation class? That would make this simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename first.
`img3` looks like it serves the purpose of being the pointer to the currentTextureSet. so when you initialise in `Player()` you might want to rename `img3` to `currentTextureSet` and then, instead of the duplicate load of `herochar_idle_anim_strip_4.png`, set
`currentTextureSet = img;`
after
(you may also want to rename `img`, `img1`, `img2` to `idleTextureSet`, `runTextureSet` and `swordAttackTextureSet`).

That aside,
definitely get rid of Timer.schedule which you are calling from render will run in a background thread you don't want that.

Looking at the asset pack here https://o-lobster.itch.io/platformmetroidvania-pixel-art-asset-pack?download if this is the same one, the images should be selected **left to right** i.e. `x` should be incremented not `y`. However, it looks like you increment `y`...
`sprite.setRegion(regions[0][frame]);` and the incorrect array access is swallowed because in a background timer task and the only textureRegion you can access is `[0][0]` i.e. you just see a single frame.

So dump this

```
  Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame++;
                if (frame > amount) {
                    frame = 0;
                }
                sprite.setRegion(regions[0][frame]);
            }
        }, 0, 1 / 12f);
```

and replace with

```
frame++;
if (frame > amount) {
frame = 0;
}
sprite.setRegion(regions[frame][0]);
```

*EDIT
So this means that your frame updates with every render, which is too fast. So the -easy fragile way- (not the best which would be deltaTime please read this excellent article https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/ ). The easy way, not the best in the case there is no time left, would be to declare

```
long renderCallCount =0;
```

put the above where frame is declared, then in your render method

```
renderCallCount++; //One more render call
if (renderCallCount % 60 == 0) { //Should I update frame?
    frame++;
    if (frame > amount) {
                    frame = 0;
    }
    sprite.setRegion(regions[0][frame]);
}
```

So whenever `renderCallCount` is divisible by `60` using the mod operator https://www.edureka.co/blog/mod-method-in-java/ , which would be once a second if your refresh rate is 60hz, then your frame is incremented. To switch frames twice a second change `60` to `30`.
This assumes your monitor is ONLY going to run at 60hz. I think your application probably depends on the timing on the refresh rate for position updates so you may want to update that in the future based on some thinking from the article. On a monitor with a faster frame rate everything will speed up (consistently).

Comment: Thanks for your Help. 
I did everything you suggested and I think my x and y was right because its animated now but since there is no timer anymore the animation runs at a really fast speed.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Ive now tried multiple things that came up my mind, a timer with delta time was the most successfull one but this lead to the same mistake I had in the beginning. So I still dont know how to avoid those Problems

Comment: Don't use a timer. To do animation, add up elapsed time by using `Graphics.getDeltaTime()` in a member field and calculate what frame should currently be shown using that.

Comment: Sorry,  but how am I supposed to do that? As I said earlier I am new to Java.

Comment: Yes so the animation would change every frame as you have a dependency on -when- the frame is rendered. But you don't know these days when your render is called.  I'lll edit the answer.

Comment: Atleast it is not super fast anymore but now it just goes through the whole animation within the renderCallCount time, which looks extremely weird.

Answer (score 0):

I just put some stuff in the right order and it now works! I dont really get why the number after the mod operator needs to be so small but otherwise it just doesnt look right. Also I know that you shouldnt create the Spritebatch in render() but when I do it in the constructor the Program just crashesbecause of the missing Spritebatch??? But thanks for the help :) Here is the working code for anyone whos interested in this:

```
public static void animation(){
    if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT) && InfoGame.cl.isGrounded() && current > Enemy.lastDmg + Enemy.dmgCool){
        currentTextureSet = attackTexture;
        amount = 3;
        tileWidth = 32;
    }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
        currentTextureSet = runTexture;
        tileWidth = 16;
        amount = 3;
    }else{
        currentTextureSet = idleTexture;
        amount = 3;
        tileWidth = 16;
    }
}

public static void changeCharacter(){
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    regions = TextureRegion.split(currentTextureSet, tileWidth, 16);
    sprite = new Sprite(regions[0][0]);
    sprite.setPosition(x,y);
    sprite.setOrigin(8,8);
    if (renderCallCount % 6 == 0) {
        frame++;
        if (frame > amount) {
            frame = 0;
        }
    }
    sprite.setRegion(regions[0][frame]);
}
```